# How to write a PHP script to find the number of indexed pages in Google?

Tags: php

I need to find the number of indexed pages in google for a specific domain name, how do we do that through a PHP script?

So,

```
    foreach ($allresponseresults as $responseresult)
    {
        $result[] = array(
            'url' => $responseresult['url'],
            'title' => $responseresult['title'],
            'abstract' => $responseresult['content'],
        );
    }
```

what do i add for the estimated number of results and how do i do that?
i know it is (estimatedResultCount) but how do i add that? and i call the title for example this way: $result['title'] so how to get the number and how to print the number?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think it would be nicer to Google to use their RESTful Search API. See this URL for an example call:

> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=site:stackoverflow.com&filter=0

(You're interested in the `estimatedResultCount` value)

In PHP you can use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) to get the data and [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) to parse it.

You can find documentation here:

> http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#fonje

---

### Example

**Warning**: The following code does not have any kind of error checking on the response!

```
function getGoogleCount($domain) {
    $content = file_get_contents('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/' .
        'search/web?v=1.0&filter=0&q=site:' . urlencode($domain));
    $data = json_decode($content);
    return intval($data->responseData->cursor->estimatedResultCount);
}

echo getGoogleCount('stackoverflow.com');
```

Comment: @Blixt: Do you know if counting the indexed pages of a website, using this API tool, has any downsides in how your website is ranked according to Google?

In other words, is it ok to make a tool on my website, which shows the user the nr of indexed pages that Google has on a URL, using the above example API?

Comment: thanks a lot mate... kinda late responding but goes to show how it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You'd load `http://www.google.com/search?q=domaingoeshere.com` with cURL and then parse the file looking for the results `<p id="resultStats"` bit.

You'd have the resulting html stored in a variable `$html` and then say something like

```
$arr = explode('<p id="resultStats"'>, $html);
$bottom = $arr[1];
$middle = explode('</p>', $bottom);
```

Please note that this is untested and a very rough example. You'd be better off parsing the html with a dedicated parser or matching the line with regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

google ajax api estimatedResultCount values doesn't give the right value.
And trying to parse html result is not a good way because google blocks after several search.

Comment: or use http://www.siteprice.org/api/ it returns google, yahoo and bing query results count and quite cheap.

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of results for `site:yourdomainhere.com` - stackoverflow.com has *about* 830k

Answer (score 0):

```
// This will give you the count what you see on search result on web page, 
//this code will give you the HTML content from file_get_contents

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=your url";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
if (FALSE === $html) {
    throw new Exception(sprintf('Failed to open HTTP URL "%s".', $url));
}

$arr = explode('<div class="sd" id="resultStats">', $html);
$bottom = $arr[1];
$middle = explode('</div>', $bottom);
echo $middle[0];

Output:
About 8,130 results

//vKj

Case 2: you can also use google api, but its count is different:
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=ursitename&callback=processResults
```

Answer (score 0):

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=site:google.com

cursor":{"resultCount":"111,000,000","
"estimatedResultCount":"111000000",