# How to get Google Indexed pages count

Tags: php, ajax, get, audit

i have to modify some tool for a company, for an SEO Audit.

My problem : I can't find the solution of number of google indexed page count. This is the actual code :

```
function get_indexed_page_count($url)
{
    $ip = $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"];
    $url = get_domain($url);
    $result = json_decode(@file_get_contents("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=site:$url&filter=0&gl=fr&userip=$ip"));
    return (int)$result->responseData->cursor->estimatedResultCount;
}
```

with this code :

```
 $indexed_pages = get_indexed_page_count($url);
print_info("Nombre de pages indéxées dans Google.fr", get_status($indexed_pages, 1.1, 0.9, "Il y a " . $indexed_pages . " pages indéxées pour ce site sur Google.fr"));
```

However, since 2016, ajax googleapis is deprecated, so i try to modify this line, but no matter, i can't solve it.

Anyone have an idea to solve my problem, and show how many pages are indexed (maybe with the "Google Custom Search" ?)  ?

Thank you.

Sincerely, Adri.

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your page, and get rid of @ in -> json_decode(@ -> you should let PHP give you some helpful hint. As using @ is like trying [to fool your mother telling her that you cleaned your room](https://z58i.imgup.net/Spring-Cledf29.gif) ^^

Comment: Here it tells me : Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/.../audit/optimisation.php on line 119. This line correspond to that : return (int)$result->responseData->cursor->estimatedResultCount;

Comment: Is there a way to get google indexed page easily ?

Comment: no warning about $ip or/and $url ?

Comment: no warning ... :(

Comment: you have topics about that already on SO -> [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139769/how-to-write-a-php-script-to-find-the-number-of-indexed-pages-in-google) or [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28080423/how-to-get-google-indexed-pages-count-via-php)

Comment: I only want to pick their code, who's what i'm research since few hours now : https://northcutt.com/tools/free-seo-tools/google-indexed-pages-checker/ But i do'nt know how they did that

Comment: OldPadawan, thank for the links, but like i said on my main post, they are all deprecated...

Comment: sorry, had not see the deprecated, just saw it when testing on my own :/ actually, after searching, seems that you need to use their up-to-date tool as stated by reponse `migrate to the Google Custom Search API (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/)`

Comment: Yup OldPadawan, i know that, but i'm a beginner in creation of SEO Tool, and i really don't know how can i use the google custom search to pick google indexed page of a specific domain... Thx. If anyone have the answer, i'm up ! Trying to do that today tho

Answer (score -1):

Why to go with so much complexity when Google has provided a much better option for us. Just verify the website through Google Webmasters:
https://www.google.com/webmasters

Add your website there, it will ask you to place a meta code on your website, I suggest to put it just above your  tag. Once added, click on verify by navigating to Google Webmasters.

Now, you need to follow the below steps in Google Webmasters:

- Navigate to "Crawl" under which you will see "Sitemaps"
- Just submit your sitemap URL which must be in .xml format. For example, if your sitemap is located here: www.xyz.com/sitemap.xml, just submit sitemap.xml there by clicking "Add Sitemap" at upper right corner.

It will then show you how many pages of the website has been indexed in Google.

The other way to find number of pages indexed is:

- Goto Google.com
- Search as below:
  site:yoursite.com
- Go to the last page of Google search. You will see a number there just below search bar which is the number of indexed pages.

But I strongly recommend to verify your website with Google Webmasters to keep an eye regularly over there.

Let me know if I can be of more help to you.

Comment: Hello Abhishek Kaushik, i know how i can find MY google indexed pages, but i'm writing a script to do it automatically via a SEO Audit.
Link just right there : http://www.seoh.fr/audit-seo/ 
Test a random site, and check the " Données liées au domaine" Section. 
"Nombre de pages indéxées dans Google.fr" means " Google indexed pages count" --> I want to fix this tool because he worked before the googleapis update (Nov. 2014)

Comment: Trying to use the Custom Search Engine... Do'esnt work for now. With a custom google search, i can however take my site informations  with my API Key and my Engine ID. I'M STUCK, Make me MAD

Comment: Hello Adrien,

I understood your point now, but coding is not my specialization. I can guide you all about SEO. If you have any query regarding SEO stuff, I will help you out.

However the logic is to fetch results from Google by searching like this:
site:yoursite.com

Visit till the last search page and count all the results and display them.

Comment: I don't know what Google is like with large popular sites, but they definitely don't index all pages of smaller not-so-popular sites. It doesn't matter if you use their site tools or search with `site:`. They only have one job to do and they are failing small sites miserably. I think this egregious deception should be publicised much more, so that governments take action against such a monopoly that is lying that it is a search engine!