# How to get total count of indexed pages in google of my website?

Tags: javascript, python, php

I want to get total count of indexed pages of my website in google. I tried many things but nothing work. So i am looking here if anyone of you can provide me some solution?

I googled alot and tried many things but nothing works in today scenario. Below are the things that i tried -

**Try no 1-**

[How to write a PHP script to find the number of indexed pages in Google?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139769/how-to-write-a-php-script-to-find-the-number-of-indexed-pages-in-google)

**Try no 2-**

[How to get Google Indexed pages count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327308/how-to-get-google-indexed-pages-count)

**Try no 3-**

```
function google(String $text) {
    // create curl resource 
    $ch = curl_init(); 

    // set url 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/search?q=$text"); 

    //return the transfer as a string 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    // $output contains the output string 
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $res = json_decode($output);
    echo $output;die;

    if($results>0) {
        curl_close($ch);            
        return true; 
    } else {
        curl_close($ch);     
        return false;
    // close curl resource to free up system resources 
    } 
} 

google("flower");
```

**Anyone please help**
**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason that you need to do this programmatically?

If you simply register your website on google search console, within a few days it will give you access to all the data you are looking for and more!
This is the proper way with wich you should manage your website on google.
It allows you to see if there are any pages with any particular issue, to see all the pages that are actively indexed and you can specify whether or not it should index a certain page, to see with which keywords your website was shown and cliked on and how many times, and so on...

Comment: Thanks @Frankini Actually i want to automate few thing based on the total number of indexed pages. Like i want to stop google bot to crawl my website when specific number reached by adding no-index or something.

Comment: Ah gotcha, i knew a few methods but they all stopped working after around 2016 and unfortunately I haven't kept up with the new methods, but i wish you luck!